# Redirect all URLs ending in "#_=_" to Root Domain

Tags: url, redirect, facebook-login, buddypress

Hi I am looking to create an htaccess redirect that takes 
`http://www.example.com/cooluser/profile#_=_` to `http://www.example.com/cooluser/members/profile/`

where `/cooluser/` is dynamic and unique to the user that is logged in. 
This is a buddypress installation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can’t do that server-side, because the hash part of an URL is not even transferred to the server, it stays client-side. Redirecting via JS would be a way to do it though.

Answer (score 2):

The URL's hash fragment (the part after `#`) is never sent to the server. The redirection needs to be done client-side, and can't be done in `.htaccess`.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to approach this for a wordpress/buddypress installation? This is the result of the new appended characters to Facebook's post-login return URL. I have tried other "login with Facebook" fixes via Javascript but none seem to work.